# how to make the css dynamical?

Tags: polymer, lit-element, lit-html

```
static get styles() {
    const width = window.innerWidth
    const height = window.innerHeight
    return css`
        :host{
            display: block;
        }
        .my-img{
            max-width: ${width}px;
            max-height: ${height}px;
        }
    `
}
```

I wrote this CSS in a web component, it works.

However, when the browser window resizes, the CSS can not change automatically.

How can I enforce it to re-calculate after window resize?

Comment: why don't you use viewport units instead of pixels ?  max-width: 100vw;

Answer (score 1):

You can use [expressions in styles](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/styles#expressions-in-static-styles) but with some caveats.

> Static styles apply to all instances of an element. Any expressions in your CSS are evaluated and included once, then reused for all instances.

[`unsafeCSS`](https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/api/modules/_lib_css_tag_.html#unsafecss) is available for use.

> if you want to inject any variable or non-literal into a css string, you must wrap it with the unsafeCSS function.

```js
class MyElement extends LitElement {
  static get styles() {
    const mainWidth = 800;
    const padding = 20;   

    return css`
      :host { 
        width: ${unsafeCSS(mainWidth + padding)}px;
      }
    `;
  } 
}
```

There is a big security warning with that though:

> ⚠️ Only use the unsafeCSS tag with trusted input. To prevent LitElement-based components from evaluating potentially malicious code, the css tag only accepts literal strings. unsafeCSS circumvents this safeguard.